# Как создать эффект пульсации при клике - `Material Design`

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Я новичок в CSS-анимации, и  стараюсь в течение последних часов, чтобы  анимация заработала. Пытаюсь понять код `Material Design`, но пока  не могу заставить его работать.

Я говорю об этом эффекте: https://angular.io/ (эффект меню). В принципе, это анимация при клике, которая распространяется по кругу от курсора мыши.

Кажется, это сводится к этим двум строкам:

```
transition: box-shadow .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
transition: box-shadow .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
```

PS: Может быть, есть какой-то код `jQuery`, который реализует эту анимацию.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to create Ripple effect on Click - Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074246/7394871) от участника  [@Antonin Cezard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4817704/antonin-cezard).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074246/how-to-create-ripple-effect-on-click-material-design/37500979#37500979

Comment: не хочу чтобы кто-то сказал что я не хвалю автора, но на самом деле ответы-то ужасные, так как не отвечают на вопрос полноценно, да и реализация хромает.

Comment: @OlmerDale потерпите немного, будет третий ответ - он лучше первых двух. Но не могу запустить без ошибок сниппет у нас.

Comment: А зачем когда есть возможность отфильтровать тащить хлам?

Comment: @OlmerDale смотрите 3 вариант  и просьба воздерживаться от резких, поучающих  комментарий. Есть, что сказать по делу - публикуйте свой код.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вариант с CSS-переменными, которые используются для раздельного использования свойства `transform`. Разделять это свойство понадобилось для того, чтобы правильно перемещать элемент (`translate3d`) и независимо от перемещения масштабировать (`scale`). Через JS так можно очень удобно управлять этими параметрами.

С точки зрения производительности это достаточно хорошая анимация такого эффекта, поскольку не делаются вставки и удаления узлов в DOM и вся работа происходит исключительно со свойствами `transform` и `opacity`, которые не влияют на композитный слой, а значит не вызывают множество перерисовок страницы.

```js
let span = document.querySelector('button span');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  span.style.setProperty('--x', e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left - span.offsetWidth/2 + 'px');
  span.style.setProperty('--y', e.clientY - this.getBoundingClientRect().top - span.offsetHeight/2 + 'px');
  
  let scaleCount = 0,
      opacityCount = 1;
      
  const animationTime = 500;

  let scaleUp = setInterval(function() {
    scaleCount += 0.25;
    span.style.setProperty('--scale', scaleCount);
    
    opacityCount -= 0.05;
    span.style.opacity = opacityCount;
  }, animationTime / 20);

  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(scaleUp);
    span.style.setProperty('--scale', 0);
  }, animationTime);
});
```

```css
body {
  --x: 0px;
  --y: 0px;
  --scale: 0;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(#c4e2fa, #c4effa);
  outline: 0;
  font: bold 17px arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: #FFF;
}

button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#c4e2fa, #c4e8fa);
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(var(--x), var(--y), 0) scale(var(--scale));
}
```

```html
<button>This is text<span></span></button>
```

Comment: Хорошая статья тут https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas, ну и вообще раздел Rendering Performance стоит изучения :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Эффект пульсации в Material Design с использованием jQuery и CSS3

[**jsBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/satuve/11/edit?html,css,js,output)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы создать **UI Ripple effect**, вам необходимо:

- **Добавить** к любому элементу `oveflow:hidden`, чтобы ограничить круг
  пульсаций (так как вы не хотите изменять ваш исходный элемент и
  поэтому с помощью `overflow` не увидите, что эффект пульсации выходит
  за пределы желаемого контейнера)
- **Добавить** к контейнеру c `overflow` просвечивающий радиальный элемент `ripple wave`
- Взять **координаты щелчка мышки**, и с помощью `CSS3` оживить
  масштабирование и непрозрачность `ripple element`
- Прослушайте событие - анимация и уничтожьте пульсацию.

**Основной код:**

В основном добавьте `data-ripple` (по умолчанию - белая рябь) или `data-ripple` = `"# 000"` для нужного элемента:

```
<a data-ripple> EDIT </a>
<div data-ripple="rgba(0,0,0, 0.3)">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* MAD-RIPPLE EFFECT */
.ripple{
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* to contain zoomed ripple */
  transform: translateZ(0);
  border-radius: inherit; /* inherit from parent (rounded buttons etc) */
  pointer-events: none; /* allow user interaction */
          animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
}
.rippleWave{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  opacity: 0.45;
          animation: ripple 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {transform: scale(24); opacity:0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(24); opacity:0;}
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // MAD-RIPPLE // (jQ+CSS)
  $(document).on("mousedown", "[data-ripple]", function(e) {

    var $self = $(this);

    if($self.is(".btn-disabled")) {
      return;
    }
    if($self.closest("[data-ripple]")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    var initPos = $self.css("position"),
        offs = $self.offset(),
        x = e.pageX - offs.left,
        y = e.pageY - offs.top,
        dia = Math.min(this.offsetHeight, this.offsetWidth, 100), // start diameter
        $ripple = $('<div/>', {class : "ripple",appendTo : $self });

    if(!initPos || initPos==="static") {
      $self.css({position:"relative"});
    }

    $('<div/>', {
      class : "rippleWave",
      css : {
        background: $self.data("ripple"),
        width: dia,
        height: dia,
        left: x - (dia/2),
        top: y - (dia/2),
      },
      appendTo : $ripple,
      one : {
        animationend : function(){
          $ripple.remove();
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

**Вот полнофункциональная демонстрация:**

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // MAD-RIPPLE // (jQ+CSS)
  $(document).on("mousedown", "[data-ripple]", function(e) {
    
    var $self = $(this);
    
    if($self.is(".btn-disabled")) {
      return;
    }
    if($self.closest("[data-ripple]")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    var initPos = $self.css("position"),
        offs = $self.offset(),
        x = e.pageX - offs.left,
        y = e.pageY - offs.top,
        dia = Math.min(this.offsetHeight, this.offsetWidth, 100), // start diameter
        $ripple = $('<div/>', {class : "ripple",appendTo : $self });
    
    if(!initPos || initPos==="static") {
      $self.css({position:"relative"});
    }
    
    $('<div/>', {
      class : "rippleWave",
      css : {
        background: $self.data("ripple"),
        width: dia,
        height: dia,
        left: x - (dia/2),
        top: y - (dia/2),
      },
      appendTo : $ripple,
      one : {
        animationend : function(){
          $ripple.remove();
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}
body{background:#f5f5f5; font: 14px/20px Roboto, sans-serif;}
h1, h2{font-weight: 300;}


/* MAD-RIPPLE EFFECT */
.ripple{
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* to contain zoomed ripple */
  transform: translateZ(0);
  border-radius: inherit; /* inherit from parent (rounded buttons etc) */
  pointer-events: none; /* allow user interaction */
          animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
}
.rippleWave{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  opacity: 0.45;
          animation: ripple 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {transform: scale(24); opacity:0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(24); opacity:0;}
}


/* MAD-BUTTONS (demo) */
[class*=mad-button-]{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0; outline: 0;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.82);
}
[class*=mad-button-] i.material-icons{
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:0;
}
.mad-button-raised{
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: /*amb*/ 0 0   2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    /*key*/ 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}.mad-button-raised:hover{
  box-shadow: /*amb*/ 0 0   2px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),
    /*key*/ 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.mad-button-action{
  width: 56px; height:56px;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
  box-shadow: /*amb*/ 0 0   2px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),
    /*key*/ 0 5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}.mad-button-action:hover{
  box-shadow: /*amb*/ 0 0   2px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
    /*key*/ 0 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
}
[class*=mad-button-].mad-ico-left  i.material-icons{ margin: 0 8px 0 -4px; }
[class*=mad-button-].mad-ico-right i.material-icons{ margin: 0 -4px 0 8px; }

/* MAD-COLORS */
.bg-primary-darker{background:#1976D2; color:#fff;}
.bg-primary{ background:#2196F3; color:#fff; }
.bg-primary.lighter{ background: #BBDEFB; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.82);}
.bg-accented{ background:#FF4081; color:#fff; }

/* MAD-CELL */
.cell{padding: 8px 16px; overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,400,300&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<div class="cell">
  <button data-ripple class="mad-button-raised mad-ico-left bg-primary"><i class="material-icons">person</i>User settings</button>
  <a data-ripple href="#" class="mad-button-action bg-accented"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
</div>

<div data-ripple class="cell bg-primary-darker">
  <h1>Click to Ripple</h1>
  <p>data-ripple</p>
</div>

<div data-ripple="rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)" class="cell bg-primary">
  <p>data-ripple="rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)"</p>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore....</p>
  <p><a data-ripple class="mad-button-raised mad-ico-right bg-accented">Edit<i class="material-icons">edit</i></a></p>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37500979/7394871) от участника  [@иRoko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Я использовал этот код раньше в нескольких моих проектах.

Используя `jQuery`, мы можем поместить эффект на него не просто статически, но и затем добавить на элемент `span` `onclick`.

Я добавил комментарии, чтобы было проще понять код.

[**Demo Here**](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/09052b957d82a17bd6ca70ac6663dd6a)

**jQuery**

```
$("div").click(function (e) {

  // Remove any old one
  $(".ripple").remove();

  // Setup
  var posX = $(this).offset().left,
      posY = $(this).offset().top,
      buttonWidth = $(this).width(),
      buttonHeight =  $(this).height();

  // Add the element
  $(this).prepend("<span class='ripple'></span>");


 // Make it round!
  if(buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
    buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
  } else {
    buttonWidth = buttonHeight; 
  }

  // Get the center of the element
  var x = e.pageX - posX - buttonWidth / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - posY - buttonHeight / 2;


  // Add the ripples CSS and start the animation
  $(".ripple").css({
    width: buttonWidth,
    height: buttonHeight,
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  }).addClass("rippleEffect");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ripple {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}
.rippleEffect {
    animation: rippleDrop .6s linear;
}

@keyframes rippleDrop {
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075725/7394871) от участника  [@Ruddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2259322/ruddy).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

На чистом `js` + `babel` -

`javascript` -

```
class ImpulseStyleFactory {
    static ANIMATION_DEFAULT_DURATION = 1;
    static ANIMATION_DEFAULT_SIZE = 300;
    static ANIMATION_RATIO = ImpulseStyleFactory.ANIMATION_DEFAULT_DURATION / ImpulseStyleFactory.ANIMATION_DEFAULT_SIZE;

    static circleImpulseStyle( x, y, size, color = `#fff`, duration = 1 ){
        return {
            width: `${ size }px`,
            height: `${ size }px`,

            background: color,

            borderRadius: `50%`,

            display: `inline-block`,

            pointerEvents: `none`,

            position: `absolute`,

            top: `${ y - size / 2 }px`,
            left: `${ x - size / 2 }px`,

            animation: `impulse ${ duration }s`,
        };
    }
}


class Impulse {
    static service = new Impulse();


    static install( container ) {
        Impulse.service.containerRegister( container );
    }
    static destroy( container ){
        Impulse.service.containerUnregister( container );
    }

    static applyToElement( {x, y}, container ){
        Impulse.service.createImpulse( x, y, container );
    }

    constructor(){
        this.impulse_clickHandler = this.impulse_clickHandler.bind(this);
        this.impulse_animationEndHandler = this.impulse_animationEndHandler.bind(this);

        this.actives = new Map();
    }

    containerRegister( container ){
        container.addEventListener('click', this.impulse_clickHandler);
    }
    containerUnregister( container ){
        container.removeEventListener('click', this.impulse_clickHandler);
    }

    createImpulse( x, y, container ){
        let { clientWidth, clientHeight } = container;

        let impulse = document.createElement('div');
        impulse.addEventListener('animationend', this.impulse_animationEndHandler);

        let size = Math.max( clientWidth, clientHeight ) * 2;
        let color = container.dataset.color;

        Object.assign(impulse.style, ImpulseStyleFactory.circleImpulseStyle(
            x, y, size, color
        ));

        if( this.actives.has( container ) ){
            this.actives.get( container )
                        .add( impulse );
        }else{
            this.actives.set( container, new Set( [ impulse ] ) );
        }

        container.dataset.active = true;

        container.appendChild( impulse );
    }


    impulse_clickHandler({ layerX, layerY, currentTarget: container }){
        this.createImpulse( layerX, layerY, container );        
    }

    impulse_animationEndHandler( {currentTarget: impulse} ){
        let { parentNode: container  } = impulse;

        this.actives.get( container )
                    .delete( impulse );

        if( ! this.actives.get( container ).size ){
            this.actives.delete( container );

            container.dataset.active = false;
        }

        container.removeChild(impulse);
    }
}
```

`css` -

```
@keyframes impulse {
    from {
        opacity: .3;

        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;

        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

использовать так -

`html` -

```
<div class="impulse" data-color="#3f1dcb" data-active="false">
    <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

`javascript` -

```
let impulses = document.querySelectorAll('.impulse');
let impulseAll = Array.from( impulses );

impulseAll.forEach( Impulse.install );
```

Живой пример с `Impulse.install` ( импульс создается в координатах клика, навешивается слушатель события `click` ) -

```js
class ImpulseStyleFactory {
static ANIMATION_DEFAULT_DURATION = 1;
static ANIMATION_DEFAULT_SIZE = 300;
static ANIMATION_RATIO = ImpulseStyleFactory.ANIMATION_DEFAULT_DURATION / ImpulseStyleFactory.ANIMATION_DEFAULT_SIZE;

static circleImpulseStyle( x, y, size, color = `#fff`, duration = 1 ){
    return {
        width: `${ size }px`,
        height: `${ size }px`,

        background: color,

        borderRadius: `50%`,

        display: `inline-block`,

        pointerEvents: `none`,

        position: `absolute`,

        top: `${ y - size / 2 }px`,
        left: `${ x - size / 2 }px`,

        animation: `impulse ${ duration }s`,
    };
}
}


class Impulse {
static service = new Impulse();


static install( container ) {
    Impulse.service.containerRegister( container );
}
static destroy( container ){
    Impulse.service.containerUnregister( container );
}

static applyToElement( {x, y}, container ){
    Impulse.service.createImpulse( x, y, container );
}

constructor(){
    this.impulse_clickHandler = this.impulse_clickHandler.bind(this);
    this.impulse_animationEndHandler = this.impulse_animationEndHandler.bind(this);

    this.actives = new Map();
}

containerRegister( container ){
    container.addEventListener('click', this.impulse_clickHandler);
}
containerUnregister( container ){
    container.removeEventListener('click', this.impulse_clickHandler);
}

createImpulse( x, y, container ){
    let { clientWidth, clientHeight } = container;

    let impulse = document.createElement('div');
    impulse.addEventListener('animationend', this.impulse_animationEndHandler);

    let size = Math.max( clientWidth, clientHeight ) * 2;
    let color = container.dataset.color;

    Object.assign(impulse.style, ImpulseStyleFactory.circleImpulseStyle(
        x, y, size, color
    ));

    if( this.actives.has( container ) ){
        this.actives.get( container )
            .add( impulse );
    }else{
        this.actives.set( container, new Set( [ impulse ] ) );
    }

    container.dataset.active = true;

    container.appendChild( impulse );
}


impulse_clickHandler({ layerX, layerY, currentTarget: container }){
    this.createImpulse( layerX, layerY, container );
}

impulse_animationEndHandler( {currentTarget: impulse} ){
    let { parentNode: container  } = impulse;

    this.actives.get( container )
        .delete( impulse );

    if( ! this.actives.get( container ).size ){
        this.actives.delete( container );

        container.dataset.active = false;
    }

    container.removeChild(impulse);
}
}



let impulses = document.querySelectorAll('.impulse');
let impulseAll = Array.from( impulses );

impulseAll.forEach( Impulse.install );
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/6.0.0/normalize.min.css";
/*@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono');*/

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

margin: 0;

position: absolute;


}

main {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

overflow: hidden;

position: relative;
}


.container {
position: absolute;

top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.centred {
display: flex;

justify-content: center;

align-items: center;
}

.shadow-xs {
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 1px 4px;
}
.sample-impulse {
transition: all .5s;

overflow: hidden;

position: relative;
}
.sample-impulse[data-active="true"] {
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.156863) 0px 3px 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.227451) 0px 3px 10px;
}



.panel {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;

background: #fff;
}


.panel__hidden-label {
color: #fff;

font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: bold;

pointer-events: none;

z-index: 1;

position: absolute;
}
.panel__default-label {
pointer-events: none;

z-index: 2;

position: absolute;
}

.sample-impulse[data-active="true"] .panel__default-label {
display: none;
}



@keyframes impulse {
from {
    opacity: .3;

    transform: scale(0);
}
to {
    opacity: 0;

    transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

```html
<main class="centred">
<div class="sample-impulse impulse centred shadow-xs" data-color="#3f1dcb" data-active="false">
    <div class="group centred">
        <div class="panel"></div>
        <span class="panel__hidden-label">StackOverflow</span>
        <span class="panel__default-label">click me</span>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Живой пример с `Impulse.applyToElement` ( координаты импульса задаются вручную, слушатель события `click` не навешивается ) -

```js
class ImpulseStyleFactory {
static ANIMATION_DEFAULT_DURATION = 1;
static ANIMATION_DEFAULT_SIZE = 300;
static ANIMATION_RATIO = ImpulseStyleFactory.ANIMATION_DEFAULT_DURATION / ImpulseStyleFactory.ANIMATION_DEFAULT_SIZE;

static circleImpulseStyle( x, y, size, color = `#fff`, duration = 1 ){
    return {
        width: `${ size }px`,
        height: `${ size }px`,

        background: color,

        borderRadius: `50%`,

        display: `inline-block`,

        pointerEvents: `none`,

        position: `absolute`,

        top: `${ y - size / 2 }px`,
        left: `${ x - size / 2 }px`,

        animation: `impulse ${ duration }s`,
    };
}
}


class Impulse {
static service = new Impulse();


static install( container ) {
    Impulse.service.containerRegister( container );
}
static destroy( container ){
    Impulse.service.containerUnregister( container );
}

static applyToElement( {x, y}, container ){
    Impulse.service.createImpulse( x, y, container );
}

constructor(){
    this.impulse_clickHandler = this.impulse_clickHandler.bind(this);
    this.impulse_animationEndHandler = this.impulse_animationEndHandler.bind(this);

    this.actives = new Map();
}

containerRegister( container ){
    container.addEventListener('click', this.impulse_clickHandler);
}
containerUnregister( container ){
    container.removeEventListener('click', this.impulse_clickHandler);
}

createImpulse( x, y, container ){
    let { clientWidth, clientHeight } = container;

    let impulse = document.createElement('div');
    impulse.addEventListener('animationend', this.impulse_animationEndHandler);

    let size = Math.max( clientWidth, clientHeight ) * 2;
    let color = container.dataset.color;

    Object.assign(impulse.style, ImpulseStyleFactory.circleImpulseStyle(
        x, y, size, color
    ));

    if( this.actives.has( container ) ){
        this.actives.get( container )
            .add( impulse );
    }else{
        this.actives.set( container, new Set( [ impulse ] ) );
    }

    container.dataset.active = true;

    container.appendChild( impulse );
}


impulse_clickHandler({ layerX, layerY, currentTarget: container }){
    this.createImpulse( layerX, layerY, container );
}

impulse_animationEndHandler( {currentTarget: impulse} ){
    let { parentNode: container  } = impulse;

    this.actives.get( container )
        .delete( impulse );

    if( ! this.actives.get( container ).size ){
        this.actives.delete( container );

        container.dataset.active = false;
    }

    container.removeChild(impulse);
}
}



const generateRandomPointByRectdAll = ( { width, height }, length = 1 ) => {
let result = [];

while( length-- ){
    result.push( {
        x: Math.round( Math.random() * width ),
        y: Math.round( Math.random() * height )
    } );
}

return result;
};

const delayTask = ( task, delay ) => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
let timeoutID = setTimeout( () => task( ), delay )
} );

document.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
const MAX_IMPULSE_DELAY_TIME = 5000;

let container = document.querySelector('.custom-impulse');
let pointAll = generateRandomPointByRectdAll( {
    width: container.clientWidth,
    height: container.clientHeight
}, 5 );
let taskAll = pointAll.map( point => () => Impulse.applyToElement( point, container ) );
let delayTaskAll = taskAll.map( task => delayTask( task, Math.round( Math.random() * MAX_IMPULSE_DELAY_TIME ) ) );
} );
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/6.0.0/normalize.min.css";
/*@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono');*/

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

margin: 0;

position: absolute;


}

main {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

overflow: hidden;

position: relative;
}

.container-fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.container {
position: absolute;

top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.centred {
display: flex;

justify-content: center;

align-items: center;
}


.custom-impulse {
will-change: transform, opasity;

position: absolute;
}


@keyframes impulse {
from {
    opacity: .3;

    transform: scale(0);
}
to {
    opacity: 0;

    transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

```html
<main class="centred">
<div class="custom-impulse container-fill centred" data-color="#3f1dcb" data-active="false">
    <span>click me</span>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T не понял, что значит ограничить?

Comment: не хочешь, оставь как есть. Я только предложил - сделать эффект внутри кнопки или другого ограниченного объекта. У тебя есть внутри кнопки эффект, остальное буйство волн на весь экран, на мой взгляд лишнее.  Как эксперимент - безусловно интересно твое решение, но его в таком виде нельзя использовать, как прикладное решение.

Comment: @Alexandr_T не, это два разных эффекта. На кнопке свой, который устанавливается как `Impulse.install` вешая на элемент прослушку click. А вот потом на другом контейнере запускается эффект устанавливаемый через `Impulse.applyToElement` где нет навешивания прослушки событий и координаты задаются вручную.

Answer (score 3):

Такая анимация может быть достигнута с помощью `box-shadows`. Размещение начала окружности под курсором мышки, при щелчке мышью потребуется `JS`.

```css
li{
    font-size:2em;
    background:rgba(51, 51, 254, 0.8);
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:2em;
    width:6em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a{color:#fff;}
a:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:10em; width:10em;
    top: -4em; left:-2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5em rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    transition: box-shadow 0.8s;
}
a:focus:after{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0em rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">button</a></li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074773/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>